# SVN merge with HTTPS hangs on FreeBSD

Tags: ssl, svn, freebsd, https, apache-2.4

I was asked to post it on here instead (original [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29350623/svn-merge-with-https-slow-on-freebsd))

I setup SVN and Apache, and when I do a `checkout` it executes normally, but whenever I try to run `svn merge` for some reason it just hangs.

Here is the output from my Apache access logs:

```
==> httpd-access.log <==
[IP_ADDRESS] - - [30/Mar/2015:10:46:47 -0400] "OPTIONS [BRANCH_PATH] HTTP/1.1" 401 381
[IP_ADDRESS] - [AUTH_USER] [30/Mar/2015:10:46:47 -0400] "OPTIONS [BRANCH_PATH] HTTP/1.1" 200 179
[IP_ADDRESS] - [AUTH_USER] [30/Mar/2015:10:46:47 -0400] "OPTIONS [BRANCH_PATH] HTTP/1.1" 200 179
[IP_ADDRESS] - [AUTH_USER] [30/Mar/2015:10:46:47 -0400] "REPORT /!svn/rvr/[REV_ID]/[BRANCH_PATH] HTTP/1.1" 200 381
[IP_ADDRESS] - - [30/Mar/2015:10:46:49 -0400] "OPTIONS [TRUNK_PATH] HTTP/1.1" 401 381
[IP_ADDRESS] - [AUTH_USER] [30/Mar/2015:10:46:49 -0400] "OPTIONS [TRUNK_PATH] HTTP/1.1" 200 179
```

I do have a similar setup (SVN + Apache) on another Debian Linux server, and everything works well on that end.

Let me know if you need any more information.